# How can I fixed url issue using htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess

My URL is:

```
WWW.example.com/?segment1/segment2
```

I want `WWW.example.com/segment1/segment2`
Please let me know how can I get using.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

To convert Querystring into url path, you can use the following rule

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{ENV_REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^([^/]+)/([^&/]+)$
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2? [L,R]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)/(.+)/?$ /?$1/$2 [L]
```

This will redirect all urls of this format **/?path/path** to **/path/path** removing the question mark.